# Analogy to Legendre's formula for $N!$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $A$ is a product of primes $p\le x$. For any $m$ let $A(m)$ be the largest such $A$ dividing $m$.

**Proposition 1.** For any $N$ sufficiently large, $$\prod_{i=1}^NA(i) < \prod_{p\le x}p^{\frac{N}{p-1}}.$$

**Question.** Can someone supply a proof for Proposition 1?

**Remarks.** It may be the case that this holds for all $N$ instead of all $N$ sufficiently large. It seems like it may be possible to prove a uniform bound in $i\le N$: $$A(i) \le \prod_{p\le x}p^{\frac{1}{p-1}},$$ but I haven't been able to do so (or rule it out).

For context, this is the first inequality in Lemma 1 of  Erdős' paper [A Generalization of a Theorem of Besicovitch.](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1936-01.pdf) Erdős mentions this is analogous to [Legendre's formula for $N!$,](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Legendre%27s_formula) but I am not sure if that is helpful for considering how to prove Proposition 1.

---

Here is a more precise definition of $A(m)$ that I am using. (Note that Erdős writes "$A$ is an integer **composed** entirely of primes not greater than $x$", so what follows is the interpretation I gave to this.) Consider the prime factorization of $m$,
$$
m = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_r^{a_r},
$$
where the primes $p_j$ are distinct for $j=1,\dots,r$, and the exponents $a_j\ge 1$. Let $$A(m) = \prod_{j : p_j \le x} p_j^{a_j}.$$

Comment: Can you clarify the first line further? IE If $  x = 10$, then $ A = 2\times 3 \times 5 \times 7$, so what is "the largest such A"?. Or, are you saying "Let $A_i$ be the product of the ith smallest primes. Let $A(m) $ be the smallest $A_i$ that divides m$?

Comment: @CalvinLin: I added to my question with some more details about $A(m)$. Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $p\le x$, the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $A(m)$ is the same as the exponent of $p$ in $m$ (this exponent is often denoted $v_p(m)$).  Essentially, $A(m)$ is just $m$ after discarding any prime factors that are $>x$.  In particular, $A(mn) = A(m) A(n)$, in other words $A$ is completely multiplicative.

So the LHS $\prod_{i=1}^N A(i)$ is equivalent to $A(\prod_{i=1}^N i) = A(N!)$.  This is the connection to Legendre's formula.

The exact value of $A(N!)$ is just $\prod_{p\le x} p^{v_p(N!)}$, and Legendre's formula gives $$v_p(N!) = \Big\lfloor \frac{N}p \Big\rfloor + \Big\lfloor \frac{N}{p^2} \Big\rfloor + \cdots.$$

Compare this to the infinite geometric series
$$\frac{N}{p-1} = \frac{N}{p} + \frac{N}{p^2} + \cdots,$$

and the inequality $v_p(N!) < N/(p-1)$ is obvious. The Proposition follows by multiplying out all of the terms (which are necessarily positive, retaining the strict inequality).  It is indeed uniform for all $N>1$, not just sufficiently large $N$.

Comment: This answer surprised me in the best way! I was not expecting such a pretty explanation, though perhaps because it's Erdős, I should have expected one :-) (+1)